# How to preserve directory when copying in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say I have a directory that looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── folder
    └── file1.sh
```

And I would like to make a docker image that preserves the directory structure such that `file1.sh` can be found in the directory `folder`. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY folder/ /app/
```

The result is that the contents of the `folder` directory are copied into the WORKDIR, but not the directory itself. The WORKDIR now looks like this:

```
.
└── file1.sh
```

Which is not what I want. I know I can change the COPY command to look like this instead

```
COPY . /app/
```

But copying the whole directory with `.` will overwrite some of the stuff I've done previously.

Is there a way to copy just that directory and preserve the directory itself?

Comment: `COPY folder/ /app/folder` ?

Comment: Yes this works. I can only do one directory at a time, but that's good enough.